# Core data use aggregate function in filter

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Is this possible to use aggregate functions in filter:

```
var expressionDescriptions = [AnyObject]()
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")
let expressionDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
expressionDescription.name = "requestsCount"
expressionDescription.expression = NSExpression(format: "@sum.requests.id")
expressionDescription.expressionResultType = .Integer32AttributeType
expressionDescriptions.append(expressionDescription)

request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "requestsCount != sitesCount")
request.propertiesToFetch = expressionDescriptions
do {
    let items = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)
} catch {
}
```

This code returns me error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath requestsCount not found
>   in entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with how you are using `NSExpression` and associated APIs. It's hard, and perhaps not necessary in your case.

Assuming this data structure:

```
Item (requests) <--->> NSSet? (Request)
     (sitesCount) Int
```

You should simply fetch all items and check in memory. This should not pose any resource constraints problems (if it does, you can optimize later):

```
filteredItems = allItems.filter { ($0.requests?.count ?? 0) != $0.sitesCount }
```